# Bessel potential space: Proof of completeness

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I want to know a proof that the (one-dimensional) Bessel potential space (for $p=2$)

$$H^s(\mathbb{R})=\left\{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}:\int_{\mathbb{R}}(1+\lvert \xi\rvert^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\lvert \hat{f}\rvert^2\,d\xi<\infty\right\}$$

is complete, even if $s<0$. I tried it myself and the case $s\ge 0$ is easy, but I can't figure out the case $s<0$. It's easy to find an isometry mapping $H^s$ into $L^2$ or $H^{-s}$ using Fourier-multipliers, because the spaces we want to map into are complete and we can use the representation theorem of Riesz. But all this approach yields for me is that the completion of $H^s$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Does anybody know a proof? I am aware that it's (probably) possible using Triebel-Lizorkin-spaces, but that seems excessive. Is there a trick involving dual spaces or closed images?

Comment: You say $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ in the definition. Are you sure that $H^s$ is actually a space of _functions_ for $s<0$ ?  I know nothing about these things, but it seems more likely to me that it's actually just a space of tempered distributions. Seems relevant to the proof of completeness...

Comment: Oops! There's a definite typo in your definition - there's no $s$ anywhere! I'd just fix it for you except I don't remember whether the exponent is supposed to be $s$ or $s/2$. Actually $s/2$, right?

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the missing $s$. I did consider the possibility that $H^s$ is merely a space of tempered distributions, I was just under the impression that is was a function space. However, I would love to know a counterexample to put my mind at ease or complete the proof, but I'm going to assume it isn't a function space from now on.

Comment: Added a counterexample to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that the definition given for $H^s$ can't be right for $s<0$; it "must" be that $H^s$ is actually the space of *tempered distributions* $f$ such that $\hat f\in L^2(\mu)$, where $d\mu(\xi)=(1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\,d\xi$.

Assuming so, this is easy: Say $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $H^s$. Then $(\hat f_n)$ is Cauchy in $L^2(\mu)$. So $\hat f_n\to g$ in $L^2(\mu)$. Now $g\in L^2(\mu)$ implies that $g$ is a tempered distribution, so $g=\hat f$ for some tempered distribution $f$, and now $f_n\to f$ in $H^s$ by definition.

---

Come to think of it, this *proves* that $H^s$ is not a space of functions (unless it's actually not complete). Say $\mathcal S$ is the Schwarz space. Then we certainly have $\mathcal S\subset H^s$, and the argument above shows that the completion of $\mathcal S$ is the space of tempered distributions that I describe.

And no, those distributions are not all functions. There exists a tempered distribution $f$ so that $\hat f$ is a function and in fact $\hat f(\xi)=\xi^{10}$. If $s<0$ is small enough (large enough? close enough to $-\infty$) then $f\in H^s$. But $f$ is certainly not a function.

Comment: Yes, that's the easy part. I was under the impression it was possible to show that $f$ is a regular distribution.

Comment: This counterexample doesn't work given the definition I used: The $H^s$ defined above is the defined as the space of all tempered distributions that are also functions, such that the fourier transforms of their distributions are also functions in $L^2(\mu)$. So the idea for the counterexample would have to be: Given a sequence of tempered distributions that are also functions, such that their Fourier transforms are also functions that converge in $L^2(\mu)$, is the pre-fourier-transform of their limit also a function?

Comment: That question is answered by the example! _If_ we take the definition as you gave it then $H^s$ is _not_ complete. Honest. If $g(\xi)=\xi^{10}$ then there exist Schwarz functions $f_n$ with $\hat f_n\to g$ in $L^2(\mu)$. Hence $(f_n)$ is Cauchy in $H^s$. But there does not exist $h$ in _your_ $H^s$ with $f_n\to h$ because $f_n$ _does_ tend to $f$ in _my_ $H^s$ (where $f$ is the tempered distribution with $\hat f=g$).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I see it now.

Comment: `Thank you for clarifying, I see it now` Not sure whether that refers to the proof that your $H^s$ is not complete or to your question about what the definition "should" be. But I've answered the first question twice, and the second once...

Comment: Don't forget the arrow and the little checkmark...